# How can I return a full table in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form and inside it a table with input and checkbox. I coded it in razor and HTML. When I press submit button I would want to receive the row marked with the checkbox or, by default, all table with updated fields. But I am receiving a null list or the first row (it depends on my controller implementation). How can achieve it? Any ideas?

This is my code, as far as I reach:

**View**:

```
@model  List<Tuto2.Models.Peliculas>
....

<div class="container">
    <h1>Lista de Peliculas</h1>
    @using(@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                ....
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Code + @i" value="@Model[i].Code" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="pull-right" type="text" id="Titulo + @i" value="@Model[i].Titulo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="pull-right" type="text" id="Genero + @i" value="@Model[i].Genero" />
                        </td>                    
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                ....
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<Peliculas> c)
{
    return View(Cartelera);
}
```

Or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Peliculas p)
{
    return View(Cartelera);
}
```

Any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your not giving your inputs a `name` attribute so there is nothing to be posted. Always use the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods to correctly generate your html - `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Code)` etc (and then view the source and study what the correct html looks like)

Comment: Although I suspect a property named `Code` is not actually a `bool` - you need a (say) `bool IsSelected` property in your view model to bind the checkbox to.

Comment: MVC model binding works using `name` instead of `id` attribute for input fields. If you want to use HTML helpers just use indexed viewmodel with `Html.CheckBoxFor`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto. Right, changing name for id works

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Right as well, can´t use checkbox for them. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you cant use a checkbox?

Comment: Need to be a bool, isn´t?

Comment: Yes, so add a `bool IsSelected` property to your view model (do not use data models when editing data). To use the asp.net-mvc framework and then generate bad html manually is just crazy

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks again, but can I return a int value in that checkbox?

Comment: Why would you even consider that. Use a view model with a `bool` property

Comment: Finally I get it. @StephenMuecke. Thanks it is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elias please use the below lines it will help you out.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    List<Peliculas> list = new List<Peliculas>();
    list.Add(new Peliculas { Code = false, Genero = "Genero1", Titulo = "Titulo1" });
    list.Add(new Peliculas { Code = false, Genero = "Genero2", Titulo = "Titulo2" });
    list.Add(new Peliculas { Code = false, Genero = "Genero3", Titulo = "Titulo3" });
    list.Add(new Peliculas { Code = false, Genero = "Genero4", Titulo = "Titulo4" });
    return View(list);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<Peliculas> c)
{
    return View(c);
}
```

View (body of loop):

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Code)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Titulo)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Genero)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @ShahzadKhan. The problem was with the attribute code is not boolean... Cheers mate

Comment: This is the way to go, using HTML Helpers. See my other comment below.

Comment: great  @peter B :)

Answer (score 0):

After researching, Just for your knowlegde. Another way for returning List of checked int using html tags is given the same name to all checkboxes and collect it in the controller. Getting a List of int that were checked plus the list of string for each row at the same field.

**cshtml**:

```
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr> 
                    <td><input class="pull-right" type="checkbox" name="code" value="@Model[i].Code" /></td>
                    <td><input class="pull-right" type="text" name="titulo" value="@Model[i].Titulo" /></td>
                    <td><input class="pull-right" type="text" name="genero" value="@Model[i].Genero" /></td>                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(List<int> code, List<string> titulo, List<string> genero)
        {
            if (code != null)
            { 
            for (int i = 0; i < Cartelera.Count; i++)
            {
                if (code.Contains(i))
                {
                    Cartelera[i].Titulo = titulo[i];
                    Cartelera[i].Genero = genero[i];
                }
            }
            }
            return View("List1", Cartelera);
         }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you do it like @Shahzad suggested. Using HTML Helpers is much easier, you always get valid HTML with valid element names, and it will bind directly to your Model class instead of binding to a bunch of random lists. You can also add Validation Attributes to your Model class, which is not possible when binding to loose lists. Using the Model class & Helpers everywhere is one of the **big strengths of ASP.NET MVC**, better to learn and embrace it!

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, but in this case I can´t modify the model so I can´t add a new field to it